# What query should i use to show status code to grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

Previously i did performance test using jmeter and already set up to grafana with influxdb but i want to show status code on my dashboard like : 200, 404, 500, 504, Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException etc. so what should i do to show the status code? Please correct me.

SELECT statuscode(errorCount) as success sum ("errorCount")/count("responseTime") FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY requestName

Comment: Suggests sharing your database scheme, otherwise your question won't make much sense.

Comment: Sorry if my grammar is bad, can i show response code like success 200 or 404 etc on dashboard grafana?

Comment: Yes. Only If the values are stored in the measurement. You need to show us your scheme